# Android Virtual Device Reset Camera Position

Tags: android-virtual-device

The Camera in my AVD has been rotated to don't know where, and I am having a hard time to rotate it back to its original position on my i5 (without GPU, at 0.1 fps).

Is there a way for me to reset the camera view?

Or best, just change the camera to a static wall paper. Because I only need to test some QR Code scanner.

Comment: My camera drifted into the abyss somehow. And I would really like to return it to the default position as well.

Answer (score 5):

in device manager, choose "Cold Boot Now", it work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your position in the virtual scene by using the default macro playbacks from your emulators extended controls.

**1. Open emulators extended controls:**
Click on the `three dots` at the control panel of your emulator and the extended controls window will open.

[image: Open devices extended controls]

**2. Reset your position:**
In the extended controls window, go to `Record and Playback` > `Macro Playback` > `Reset position` > `Play`.

Now when you open the camera in your emulato, your position will be reset.

[image: Reset position]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to change the AVD config.
In the AVD Manager you can `edit` the AVD.
Under advanced settings there is a `Camera` section and I changed the back facing camera to my `webcam`, saved the change and tested it.
Then I went back and changed the setting back to `VirtualScene`, saved it and the camera showed the Virtual Scene and was back to original position.